# Register users to receive alerts for multiple lists

Tags: list, alert, user-accounts

I would like to create an application which is started up from a webpart on a SharePoint (2010) site that allows users to register to receive alerts for changes/additions to a collection of four different lists on the site. In other words, I want to register then for the alerts for each of the lists without the user having go pull up each list and set an alert for themselves.  Any thoughts on how this can be accomplished?

Comment: I don't know what your implementation plans were, there aren't any client side web services to do to this, you'll need to use server side code, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spalertcollection_methods(v=office.14).aspx